# How to loop throught all version url

Tags: bash, shell

I have a software which have several version and can be upgraded from version 1 to 5. To upgrade, we need to retreive the version 2, 3, 4 and lastly 5. How can I loop for all version ? Here is my attempt :

```
#!/bin/bash
version=1
while [ wget --spider https://download.software/server/releases/latest-"$version".tar.bz2 2>/dev/null ]
do
   version=$((version+1))
   echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem were the braces `[]`. `[` itself is a command. To check the exit status of `wget` in a loop, simply use `while wget ...; do ...; done`.

However, you don't need the loop at all. `wget` can work with multiple URLs in one call and `bash` can generate the URLs using brace expansion `{1..5}`:

```
#! /bin/bash
wget https://download.software/server/releases/latest-{1..5}.tar.bz2
```

Comment: If I don't know the latest version ? How can I determine it. Also I make some action with each version. So I think I need to use a loop

Comment: If you don't know the last version a loop may be better. As I said, your script is fine. Just remove the `[ ]` around `wget`. As a hack you could also use `{1..99}` and ignore the errors for non-existent files.

Comment: I used `wget https://download.software/server/releases/latest-{1..5}.tar.bz2` but it's infinite looping

Comment: Did you use it inside a loop? It should be really just that one command, nothing more.

Comment: Do you know how I can loop for all of these file downloaded ? I need to make some action on the version 2 and on 3 and so on...

Comment: Yes. For each successfully downloaded URL `wget` should create a file named like the last part of that URL. To loop over these files use `for file in latest-*.tar.bz2; do ...; done`.

Comment: It's working great ! Thank you. Just a last question, I tried to put a variable in the range but it's outputing an error 404. `{11.."$latest"}`

Comment: Brace expansion does not work with variables. Use a loop instead: `for ver in $(seq 1 "$latest"); do wget "URL/latest-$ver.tar.bz2"; done`

Comment: Avoid `seq`; it's no more standard than a C-style loop `for ((i=1; i <= $lastest; i++)); do`, so prefer the loop (as syntax supported by the shell) to an external program that may or may not be available.

Comment: @chepner So I replace `for ver in $(seq "$version" "$latest");` by `for ((i=1; i <= $lastest; i++));` ? But how do I get the current version the for loop ?

Comment: Just replace `i` with `ver`. I was on autopilot when I typed that; I always use `i` as my loop index.

Answer (score 0):

@Socowi's answer is good if you want to download one at a time. If you prefer downloading in parallel:

```
parallel -j0 wget https://download.software/server/releases/latest-{}.tar.bz2 ::: {1..5}
```